# How can I join two tables by a foreign key table in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to join two tables by a foreign key table in linq.
The two tables are
Items and Classes, and the foreign key table is ItemClasses (ItemId, ClassId).

My context does not have a DBSet for the foreign key table, and when I try to add it I get a model creation error.

When I saw the error, I noticed that this code referred to the foreign key table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Classes>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Items)
            .WithMany(e => e.Classes)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ItemClasses").MapLeftKey("ClassId").MapRightKey("ItemId"));
```

So it looks like I should be able to refer to the items through the class, but how do I join the tables?

I'd like to do something like this

```
            query = from ig in myCtx.Items.AsNoTracking()                          
                         //join di in myCtx.ItemClasses.AsNoTracking() on ig.Id equals di.ClassId
                         join c in myCtx.Classes.AsNoTracking() on di.ClassId equals c.Id
                         join dd in myCtx.SalesAssociates.AsNoTracking() on dd.Id equals ig.SalesAssociateId
```

How do I do joins when the fk table is not in my context, but is referred to in one of the tables?

Comment: You don't have to join at all. Just use `class.Items` in your LINQ query. That's what these *navigation properties* are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a configuration error. With `HasMany` / `WithMany` you are actually configuring the automatic "link" table, so

```
m.ToTable("Classes")
```

should be

```
m.ToTable("ItemClasses")
```

or how exactly you want that table to be named in the database.

Second, when working with EF, it's always preferred to [use navigation properties rather than joins](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/). In case of `many-to-many` relationship with auto link table, using navigation properties is mandatory. EF will produce the necessary joins for you.

So instead of join your would use something like this:

```
query = from ig in myCtx.Items.AsNoTracking()                          
        from c in ig.Classes
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you could chain from in a query like that. That's what I was looking for. (The configuration error you spotted was a mistake on my part. I will edit.)